# Информация про уровни модели OSI

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, osi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, книги, статьи или другие источники про уровни модели OSI. Хочется углубиться в каждый уровень подробнее, чем описание в той же книге Олифера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как по мне, так в Википедии весьма неплохо описано. На самом деле эти модели никакого практического смысла не имеют. Только академический, они помогают новичкам понять, как оно всё устроено. Ну и для разработчиков всяких новых технологий и протоколов могут послужить руководством.

А в работе за 12 лет сисадминства и 5 лет написания кода разного уровня, мне это именно в тех терминах, в которых описано, не пригодилось. Вот без гугла навскидку: физический, транспортный, канальный, прикладной, какие там ещё? А ведь я с ходу, даже если ночью разбудить, могу отличить L2TP и IPSec от PPPoE, и рассказать как как каждый из них устроен и как работает. И что про HTTP написано в RFC 2616 - тоже без гугла расскажу.

Так что вникать я вам советую не в модель OSI, а в то, о чём на говорит, а говорит она вам не путать природу и назначение разных её слоёв.

Comment: Мне кажется, если хочется во что то углубиться, то более полезной может быть книга Стивенса "UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений". Я вроде не совсем тупой в сетях, но полгода назад я взял её в руки и оторвался часа через 4 - читается как детектив. И после я, например, понял, почему мои друзья - HFT- шники всем дистрибутивам линукса предпочитают FreeBSD (или CentOS в некотрых случаях). И, кажется, там есть глава про уровни модели OSI.

Comment: @S.H. я с фряхи и не слезал никогда. Так получилось. А центось больше любят в корп. сегменте.

Comment: я имел в виду особенности реализации select и poll, которые позволяют им сэкономить несколько наносекунд. Насколько я знаю, FreeBSD пользовалась большой популярностью во времена Демоса, когда интернет только - только появился. И, видимо, с тех пор она людям нравится :-) А любовь к центоси (r.i.p.) - это, наверное, следствие того, что "центось - это бесплатный редхат". Посмотрим, что сейчас будет. Замес с тем, что MS активно вкладывается в opensource - может получиться весьма интересный :-)

Comment: @S.H. то что сетевое ядро у фряхи божественное и линукс suck по производительности - это каждому фряшнику известно. :) Я писал простую апишечку на базе сервачка мощностью как мой телефон, в стеке фря+Erlang+мускуль. Он кушал почти 1кк rps и не кашлял. А для ASP.NET сейчас для такой пропускной способности требуется суперкомпьютер за лярд лярдов мегабаксов с 10 сетевухами. Разрыв в технологиях гигантский, мелкомякгим ещё пилить и пилить до чего-то вменяемого, чтобы выйти в сеть нормально.

Comment: "сетевое ядро у фряхи божественное" - надо такой значок заказать :-) Эмоционально я на Вашей стороне. В деталях - было бы интересно поразбираться, но это далеко выходит за пределы заданного вопроса :-) Мне всегда ASP.NET казалась сильно распухшей. Интереснее то, что сейчас NET наконец работает под линуксом. А там есть гораздо более экономные HTTP-сервера. Появилась альтернатива.